# FUSE inside Docker

Tags: docker, fuse

I'm trying to install and use FUSE inside a Docker container. My Dockerfile is the following:

```
FROM golang:1.8

WORKDIR /go/src/app
COPY . .

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y fuse && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN go-wrapper download
RUN go-wrapper install

CMD ["go-wrapper", "run", "/mnt"]
```

When I run the program mounting FUSE, I get: `/bin/fusermount: fuse device not found, try 'modprobe fuse' first`.

If I install `kmod` and run `modprobe fuse` during the build step, I get the error:

`modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:557 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.4.104-boot2docker/modules.dep.bin'`

How can I fix this?

Comment: How do you run the container? Do you specify --privileged mode?

Comment: I use `docker run -it --rm`. Adding `--privileged` does not help with the `modprobe` error message, nor with the FUSE one.

Answer (score 66):

With respect to Nickolay's answer below, the `--privileged` flag is not strictly required, for fuse. And you're **best to avoid** giving that much privilege to your container.

You should be able to get things working by replacing it with `--cap-add SYS_ADMIN` like below.

```
docker run -d --rm \
           --device /dev/fuse \
           --cap-add SYS_ADMIN \
      <image_id/name>
```

Sometimes this may not work. In this case, you should try and tweak the **AppArmor profile** or just disable it as follows:

```
docker run -d --rm \
           --device /dev/fuse \
           --cap-add SYS_ADMIN \
           --security-opt apparmor:unconfined \
      <image_id/name>
```

Finally, if all fails, use --privileged flag.

Comment: Isn't the SYS_ADMIN cap basically equivalent to running the container in privileged mode?

Comment: @Ibrahim SYS_ADMIN is one of the things --privileged adds, but --privileged also removes a lot more protections Docker provides by default (default cgroups, seccomp profiles, etc etc etc) such that the net result is that specifying --cap-add SYS_ADMIN is *much* more secure than --privileged

Comment: I think `--device /dev/fuse` should not be included in the docker run cmd. That gives the container access to the _host's_  /dev/fuse, which is not what was requested, IIUC.

Comment: @GenericRatzlaugh It's the same kernel and, thus, the same `/dev/fuse`. (Device files are basically just aliases for kernel interfaces.) You need it to interface with FUSE but you can then use user namespaces to add isolation starting with kernel version 4.18. See [docker/for-linux#321](https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/321) for details.

Comment: @nickgryg response about using --device /dev/fuse is better

Answer (score 5):

Just as a workaround you can do the `modprobe fuse` on your host, then using `--device /dev/fuse` to get the device in the container. Anyway container should be started in privileged mode to mount things with the `/dev/fuse`.

The command to run the docker image is:

```
docker run -d --rm --device /dev/fuse --privileged <image_id/name>
```

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. Ideally, I would like it to work on OSX too and I don't know if there's any way to emulate `/dev/fuse` on it.

Comment: This is probably the solution, as a docker jail does not run its own kernel, so you need to have the module loaded outside of the jail and the device access allowed by the host. Take care and check if the fuse device can be used to break out of the jail.

Comment: I know I'm late to the party but re: `/dev/fuse` on OS X, Fuse for OS X works great and can be installed via `brew`: `brew install osxfuse` or https://osxfuse.github.io/

Comment: As Gary notes above, the --privileged option should be used very carefully. More details (on the risks) in this Medium post: https://medium.com/lucjuggery/docker-tips-mind-the-privileged-flag-d6e2ae71bdb4

Comment: is there a non-paywalled version of that post, @Drew?