# How to pass docker switches to gcloud ai-platform?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-ml

I am [submitting jobs to GCP AI Platform](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/ai-platform/jobs/submit/training) as

```
gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training "${job_name}" \
    --job-dir="gs://${job_root}/${job_name}" \
    --region=${region} \
    --master-image-uri=${image_uri} \
    --scale-tier=basic_gpu \
    --python-version=3.7 \
    -- \
    --other-args
```

But my custom image needs docker to run with [`--ipc=host`](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/unable-to-write-to-file-torch-18692-1954506624/9990). Is it possible to add this switch?

**UPDATE**: never mind the `--ipc=host` switch because as pointed out in the comment it shouldn't be needed (and it's not). Now I have to pass [`--device /dev/fuse --cap-add SYS_ADMIN`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49021109) to ai-platform's docker so that I can mount GCP bucket to docker image's file system with `gcsfuse`. Any ideas? Hacking `gcloud` is acceptable (by e.g., replacing part of the sources of `gcloud` inside the docker image), but I am not sure where the `docker` command is inside `gcloud`'s source code.

Comment: The service already increased the value for shm-size, so it should just work. Can you give a try please? Also we have official pytorch support, maybe you can simply use the service's official container images.

Comment: @GuoqingXu Right, it's actually working, but just taking hours between model building and training starting for some reason, so that I thought it halted. For the image, I am training with [nnUNet](https://github.com/MIC-DKFZ/nnUNet), which requires PyTorch 1.6 and thus CUDA 10.1, and I think the official image has PyTorch up to 1.4 and CUDA up to 10.0?

Comment: @GuoqingXu but is there a way to set the [switches](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#operator-exclusive-options) generally?

Comment: To look into this further, can you please give a complete example of how you would like this to work?

Comment: We only provide knobs to enable ML training. For the issue you were facing, can you send your job id to cloudml-feedback@google.com please? The delay might be caused by lack of quota (we queue your jobs if you don't have enough quota). Here is the get started doc for pytorch FYI. https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/getting-started-pytorch

Comment: @MrTech An simplified version of the command is attached. As pointed out in my other comments I actually don't need that switch to make things work, but it's still good to know how to add general docker switches for `gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training`.

Comment: @GuoqingXu never mind the delay, the jobs work pretty nice now. But currently I need to add `--device /dev/fuse --cap-add SYS_ADMIN` to ai-platform's docker so that I can utilize `gcsfuse` to mount GCP's bucket onto image's file system. Do you have ideas? (original question updated)

Comment: Can you share the machine configs you are using for the training job? It would also be helpful if you can share your job id and config steps with cloudml-feedback@google.com for further investigation.