# Trying to connect google drive to paperspace gradient notebook

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm trying to mount google drive to paperspace notebook using google-drive-ocamlfuse with the following code

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alessandro-strada/ppa
sudo apt update && sudo apt install google-drive-ocamlfuse
```

but when launching with

```
google-drive-ocamlfuse
```

there's an error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: firefox: not found
/bin/sh: 1: google-chrome: not found
/bin/sh: 1: chromium-browser: not found
/bin/sh: 1: open: not found
Cannot retrieve auth tokens.
Failure("Error opening URL:https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=..........
```

ocamlfuse's github page has instructions on "Headless Usage & Authorization" but it's for local machine not for something like paperspace.
is there any way i can use google-drive-ocamlfuse to mount the drive?

is there any other better/simpler method to mount google drive on paperspace gradient?

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** 
There is no way to mount Google Drive as filesystem on paperspace gradient.

**Long answer:** 
Your error message says cannot open browser. You are correct, should use headless mode [https://github.com/astrada/google-drive-ocamlfuse/wiki/Headless-Usage-&-Authorization]. Basically create an OAuth App, note down the `client-id` and `client-secret`, then authenticate using `google-drive-ocamlfuse -headless -id client-id -secret client-secret`.

But even if the authentication step success, you will still encounter error like `fuse: device not found, try 'modprobe fuse' first`. It is because Paperspace gradient notebook is running as container. A container cannot perform `fuse` operation unless it has `SYS_ADMIN` capability. (See [FUSE inside Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48402218/fuse-inside-docker)). In this case, we have no control on how paperspace running their container. So we are unable to mount filesystem on paperspace gradient.

However, you can use something like https://github.com/iterative/PyDrive2 to access Google Drive file.